# Switch back to CSS icons in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the `vscode-icons` I've just installed the PostCSS Language Support plugin and CSS files now the PostCSS icon instead CSS icons. I would like to go back to the old CSS icons how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I've found the answer, in `settings.json`, add the following:

```
{
  "vsicons.associations.files": [
    { "icon": "css", "extensions": ["css"], "format": "svg" }
  ],
}
```